# TypeScript as cast only fails when both non-optional interface property missing and extra property present

Tags: typescript, object, interface, casting

I was running `tsc` locally on an `example.ts` and I expected a warning or error for the `onePropMissing`, as `c` is not an optional property on the interface, yet, in `onePropMissing` the `c` property is missing and I don't get any errors.

After that, I added an example, `oneExtraProp`, which I also expected to fail, because there's one more property.

After these two examples, I was quite sure that `extraAndOneMissing` would be fine as well, though, to my surprise, TSC complained here.

```
interface InterfaceEverythingRequired {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: number;
}
// Expected to be OK, it's OK
const allPropsPresent = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 1 } as InterfaceEverythingRequired;
// Expected warning as c is missing, but TSC says it's OK
const onePropMissing = { a: 'a', b: 'b' } as InterfaceEverythingRequired;
// Expected warning as extraProp is present, but TSC says it's OK
const oneExtraProp = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 3, extraProp: 'no-issues' } as InterfaceEverythingRequired;
// After the last two examples, I expected to have no warnings, as
// there were no warnings for the extra property, nor the missing property
// but TSC complained
const extraAndOneMissing = { a: 'a', b: 'b', extraProp: 'what?' } as InterfaceEverythingRequired;
```

What is happening here and why do errors behave so interestingly?

The error I got:

```
Type '{ a: string; b: string; extraProp: string; }' cannot be 
converted to type 'InterfaceEverythingRequired'.
  Property 'c' is missing in type '{ a: string; b: string; 
extraProp: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `as` to type your variables. Type them directly instead

```
const onePropMissing: InterfaceEverythingRequired = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }; // error
```

Type casts in TypeScript are only type assertions really, and the structural type system of TypeScript leads to a lot of unexpected results when coming from a nominally typed language.

A lot of the typical traps are addressed in the [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: The most relevant section is https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-this-incorrect-cast-throw-a-runtime-error

Comment: Quote from FAQ: TypeScript has type assertions, not type casts. The intent of <T>x is to say "TypeScript, please treat x as a T", not to perform a type-safe run-time conversion.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your examples like the following, you'll get better error messages:

```
const allPropsPresent: InterfaceEverythingRequired = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 1 };
// Ok
const onePropMissing: InterfaceEverythingRequired = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
// Property 'c' is missing
const oneExtraProp: InterfaceEverythingRequired = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 3, extraProp: 'no-issues' }
// Object literals may only specify known properties
const extraAndOneMissing: InterfaceEverythingRequired = { a: 'a', b: 'b', extraProp: 'what?' };
// Object literals may only specify known properties
```

Now to your question, why type assertions work for all cases except for the last one, you need to consider the structural typing in TypeScript:

`{ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 1 }` is a subtype of `{ a: 'a', b: 'b' }` because it has all the properties of the super type.

```
let x: { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 1 };
let y: { a: 'a', b: 'b' };
x = y; // error
y = x; // OK
```

But you can write `x = y as { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 1 }` as it downcasts `y`, and the error disappears.

For your third example, `{ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 3, extraProp: 'no-issues' }` is a subtype of `InterfaceEverythingRequired` so the type assertion (downcast) works. In your fourth example `{ a: 'a', b: 'b', extraProp: 'what?' }` and `InterfaceEverythingRequired` are unrelated types (they do not have sub-type super-type relationshiop) and TypeScript doesn't allow downcasting in such cases. Your fourth example is similar to the following case:

```
let x: string;
let y: number;

x = y as string; // Type 'number' cannot be converted to type 'string'
```